# How to CSS Display:table grow right

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm working on a website that involves displaying details from a mysql database using PHP.

The script dynamically creates a new div for every row found that is stored in an associative array.

The output html looks like:

```
<div class="itembox">
<img class="item_img" src="superman.jpg" />
<span class="item_text"><strong>Comic Name</strong></span>
<span class="item_text">Comic Author</span>
    <span class="item_text">Comic Publisher</span>
<span class="item_text">$25.00</span>
<a class="item_text" href="addtocart.html">Add to Cart</a>
</div>
```

and the CSS for it:

```
.itembox
{
background-color:#F2F2F2;
position:relative;
top:300px;
border:solid 1px black;
width:60%;
height:60px;
margin:10px auto;
display:table;
table-layout:fixed;
overflow:hidden;
}

.item_img
{
max-height:50px;
margin:5px 0 5px 5px;
}

.item_text
{
position:relative;
left:30px;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
width:19%;
}
```

The problem that I am having is that the  tag is only displayed if the user's session variable is set (i.e user is logged in), so the link won't always be there. When it is removed, all the span elements with class="item_text" are shifted right, leaving a gap between the img and the spans. So the way the CSS is currently layed it, it slots the  link to the right and shifts all the .item_text elements to the left. Is there a way to just have it fixed to the left already and have the blank space on the right, which is populated when I need?

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find anything specific to the display:table or display:table-cell properties of CSS that let me alter that. Also, adding text-align:left to .itembox proved to do nothing.

Comment: Have you tried some `display:inline-block`for each element instead of `table` & `table-cell`?

Comment: "the tag is only displayed if the user's session variable is set" ... Which bit is "the tag"? Could you perhaps post separate examples of the page HTML with and without the user logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a real `<table>` element. This looks like tabular data, so a table is appropriate:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img class="item_img" src="superman.jpg" /></td>
    <td class="item_text"><strong>Comic Name</strong></td>
    <td class="item_text">Comic Author</td>
    <td class="item_text">Comic Publisher</Td>
    <td class="item_text">$25.00</td>
    <td><a class="item_text" href="addtocart.html">Add to Cart</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If all "Add to Cart" links appear only when the user is logged in, the entire column will be gone and no resizing is needed.

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how many budding webdevelopers take the *"don't use tables for layout"* adagium so literally they forget the last 2 words of it. I've really had discussions with people that wouldn't believe it's still ok to use a `<table>` when you're displaying a rectangular block of data with data organized in rows and columns with both vertical and horizontal relationship.

Comment: I initially did have it set up as a raw table with no CSS associated but wasn't sure if I wanted it structurally layed out in a tabular manner. I guess I'll just go with it and CSS it properly so it still displays the same. Thanks everyone :)